# Modify the Search Navigation display template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, navigation, display-template

Can we modify the search navigation web part display template? I wish to add a bottom border to the selected page navigation header.

[image: Search Navigation Header]

Comment: CSS is your friend!

Comment: With css, either i have to add the script in the master page (Not allowed in my environment) or add a script editor webpart in each results page (Not scalable). Any other leads would be appreciated.